# Query against a Deserialized JSON object

Tags: c#, json, linq

I am using json convert to create a DtoPolicy object. I would like to be able to query against this to get the result set that i need. Visual Studio tells me that the IEnumerable I am trying to query against has no definition of FindByExp. I think it has to do with the fact that it comes across as Json and then gets deserialized. Has anyone had success querying against an object like this?

```
EligiblePolicies = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<DtoPolicy>>(_app2Lead._app2Queries.ResponseFromWebServices);
var Eligible2 = EligiblePolicies.FindByExp(bigredsquiggleshere)(x => x.PolicyIssueDate >= DateTime.Today);
```

Comment: Why can't you use `Where()`?

Comment: Oh my gosh! Please put that as an answer. Thank you!

Comment: JsonConvert doesn't implement `FindByExp` function, that sounds like some sort of custom interface implementation by some senior software engineer haha lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use [.Where()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx).

Example:

```
var Eligible2 = EligiblePolicies.Where(x => x.PolicyIssueDate >= DateTime.Today);
```